# Get Node from link

Tags: views, 8, hooks, feeds

Within the `mymodule_preprocess_views_view_row_rss(&$variables)` hook, we are able to get the `link` by using `$variables['row']->link`. However, we are not able to access the `node` for which that `link` is for.

**How can we use the value returned from `$variables['row']->link` to get the `node`?**

Goal(s):

1. Using the `link` value, get the `node` so that we can fetch additional fields such as `field_image` within the hook
2. Add the `field_image` as a variable to `$variables` array so that it can be used in the `views-view-row-rss.html.twig` file.

We tried with no success.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_row_rss(&$variables) {
  $link_value = $variables['row']->link;
  $path = \Drupal::service(`path.alias_manager`)->getPathByAlias($link_value);
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($path);
  ksm($node); // returns null. 
}
```

Additional view settings we tried with no success:

Under Fields

- Added `field_image` field

Format

- Format: RSS Feed

Within `mymodule_preprocess_views_view_row_rss(&$variables)` hook, we tried printing all the variables using `ksm($variables)` to see if `field_image` was returned, but it was not.

Comment: Any reason you’re not adding the data you need to the View as normal? Then it’d already be there, no manual intervention required

Comment: @Clive I additional some details regarding the `view settings`. When we tried adding the `field_image`, it was still not accessible in the hook and twig template.